# My Character spins uncontrollably when ever I change it's physics to character in BGE

Tags: game-engine, armature, .fbx

so Iv'e been having this problem, that I have no idea how to fix. My Character spins uncontrollably when ever I change it's physics to character in BGE, and I cant get it to stop. I imported the character file from FBX to blender, and I think it has something to do with that[image: I added motion blur so you guys could see it]